# Probability Distribution Deciding Which Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Three Men toss coins to see who pays for coffee. If all three match, they toss again. Otherwise, the odd man pays for coffee. What is the probability of tossing at most twice?

I cannot seem to get anywhere with this problem. What distribution should I use and why? Please, any help.

Comment: There are 8 equally likely sequences of flips. Two of them, namely HHH and TTT, have a full match. So they play again with probability 1/4. Do you know what to do now?

Comment: Would this be a geometric distribution?

Comment: That's right. ${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

So, they get different results the first time or the same results the first time but different results the second time.

The probability of getting different results is$\frac18$ times the numbr of possibilities of getting different results: **HHT,HTH,THH,TTH,THT,HTT**, that is the probability of getting different results is $$\frac68=\frac34.$$

The probability of getting the same results is $\frac18$ times the number of possibilities: **HHH,TTT**. That is the probability is $$\frac28=\frac14.$$

The probability that they have to flip the coin only once or twice is

$$\frac34+\frac14\cdot\frac34=\frac{15}{16}.$$

Comment: Ok I see, but what probability distribution are you using?

Comment: I don't think that there is a name...

Comment: It is a geometric distribution. Thanks zoli.